# Erro ao centralizar ul em div

Tags: css, css3

tenho o html abaixo e o seu css.

Por mais que eu tente, não estou conseguindo centralizar a lista ul na div.
Essa ul traz dados de uma pesquisa ao banco. Onde estou errando?

```css
  *
  {
    width:100%;
  }

  .body
  { 
    width: 100%;;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  ul {
      list-style-type:none;
      padding:0;
  }
////////////////////////// INICIO LISTAGENS ////////////////
div.divLista, div.divListaItens {
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}

ul.listaTopo, ul.listaRegistros {
clear:both;
width:95%;
}


ul li.listaTopoLi {
float:left;
background-color:#000; 
color:#fff;
height:50px;
line-height:50px;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;
margin: 0 auto;
padding:0;
}
////////////////////////// FIM LISTAGENS //////////////////
```

```html
<div class="divListaItens">
 <ul class="listaRegistros">

    <li class='listaTopoLi' style='text-align:left; width:100px; background-color:#CCC; color:#FFF'>Super</li>     
    <li class='listaTopoLi' style='text-align:left; width:400px; background-color:#CCC; color:#FFF'>Carlos Alberto Rocha</li>
    <li class='listaTopoLi' style='text-align:center; width:100px; background-color:#CCC; color:#FFF'>caca</li>     
    <li class='listaTopoLi' style='text-align:center; width:100px; background-color:#CCC; color:#FFF'><a href='' onclick="return verifica('Deseja Bloquear este Administrador?')" '><img src='_img/bloquear.png' height=30px  title='Bloquear Administrador' /></a></li>   
    <li class='listaTopoLi' style='text-align:center; width:100px; background-color:#CCC; color:#FFF'><a href='administradoresEditar.php?acao=form&idAdmin=1'><img src='_img/editar.png' height='30px' title='Editar Administrador' /></a></li>    
    <li class='listaTopoLi' style='text-align:center; width:100px; background-color:#CCC; color:#FFF'><a href='' onclick="return verifica('Deseja Excluir este Administrador?')" '><img src='_img/excluir.png' height='30px'  title='Excluir Administrador'/></a></li>
 </ul>


  <ul class='listaRegistros'>
    <li class='listaTopoLi' style='text-align:left; width:100px; background-color:#FFF; color:#CCC'>Comum</li>
    <li class='listaTopoLi' style='text-align:left; width:400px; background-color:#FFF; color:#CCC'>José Mário</li>
    <li class='listaTopoLi' style='text-align:center; width:100px; background-color:#FFF; color:#CCC'>jose</li>
    <li class='listaTopoLi' style='text-align:center; width:100px; background-color:#FFF; color:#CCC'><a href='' onclick="return verifica('Deseja Bloquear este Administrador?')" '><img src='_img/bloquear.png' height=30px  title='Bloquear Administrador' /></a></li>
    <li class='listaTopoLi' style='text-align:center; width:100px; background-color:#FFF; color:#CCC'><a href='administradoresEditar.php?acao=form&idAdmin=2'><img src='_img/editar.png' height='30px' title='Editar Administrador' /></a></li>
    <li class='listaTopoLi' style='text-align:center; width:100px; background-color:#FFF; color:#CCC'><a href='' onclick="return verifica('Deseja Excluir este Administrador?')" '><img src='_img/excluir.png' height='30px'  title='Excluir Administrador'/></a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa Tarde,

Acredito que em dois pontos:

Primeiro - No seu CSS já existe

```
text-align: center
```

Não há necessidade de inserir ele novamente em

```
<li class='listaTopoLi' style='text-align:center;
```

E acredito que ele está prevalecendo o atributo float inserido na css:

```
ul li.listaTopoLi {
    float:left;
    background-color:#000; 
    color:#fff;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Mas o que estou querendo centralizar é a ul inteira dentro de uma div que tem width: 100%. Então não devo estar entendendo a sua resposta!

Comment: Sim. Uso Dreamweaver. Essa é a saída que o navegador liberou de um foreach php. Peguei pelo exibir código fonte (Ctr + U). Copiei apenas essa parte do código e fiz um arquivo html à parte e deu o mesmo erro!

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou colocar a centralização nesta parte do css?

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: já, não deu certo

Comment: Você está usando algum programa gráfico para visualizar (ex. Dreamweaver)? Ou está no código puro mesmo? Já tentou jogar centralizar direto no html?
Não creio que seja o float porque pelo que parece ele é específico para o li...

Comment: Sim. Uso Dreamweaver. Essa é a saída que o navegador liberou de um foreach php. Peguei pelo exibir código fonte (Ctr + U). Copiei apenas essa parte do código e fiz um arquivo html à parte e deu o mesmo erro!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui.

Para Alinhar a `div` ao centro, basta `margear` 0 para todo lado.

```
div.divLista, div.divListaItens {
    margin: auto;
}
```

Temos então a `div` alinhada ao centro igual ao `reset` da própria página.

Após isso, basta adicionar o tamanho da div se caso em cada página ela puder ter valor diferente.

```
<div class="divLista" style="width:950px">
  <ul class="listaTopo">
     <li class="listaTopoLi" style="width:100px">DATA</li>
     <li class="listaTopoLi" style="width:150px">NOME</li>
     <li class="listaTopoLi" style="width:150px">EMAIL</li>
     <li class="listaTopoLi" style="width:150px">TELEFONE</li>
     <li class="listaTopoLi" style="width:100px">ASSUNTO</li>
     <li class="listaTopoLi" style="width:100px">RESPONDER</li>
     <li class="listaTopoLi" style="width:100px">RESPONDIDO</li>
     <li class="listaTopoLi" style="width:100px">EXCLUIR</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="divListaItens" style="width:950px">
 <ul class="listaRegistros">

  <?php       
     $contador = 0;

     foreach( $emails as $chave=>$email)
     {
       $contador++;
       <li></li>
     }
  ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Quanto a alinhar o conteúdo da `div` ao centro, basta adicionar o `estilo` `align`

```
div.divLista, div.divListaItens {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Nessa parte:

```
ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;
}
```

Acrescente: `text-align: center;`