# Reset atrapalhando centralizar

Tags: css3

Estou com um problema e um pouco de vergonha em pedir ajuda.

Hoje ainda resolvi um problema semelhante em: [Erro ao centralizar ul em div](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123200/erro-ao-centralizar-ul-em-div)

Porém, resolvi apenas fazendo `margin:auto` na `div` e centralizando uma ul.

Agora, o problema se deu ao contrário. é o `margin: auto` é quem não está permitindo a centralização do `nav`.

Fui eliminando quase tudo no meu código até chegar nesse pedaço de código.

O que eu faço?

```css
* {
  padding:0 auto;
  margin:0 auto;
  font-family: Arial;
}

body { 
  color: #CCC;
}

ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
}

a, a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFF;    
}

.menuNav {
  height:50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:#3E4095; 
}

ul li.menuTopo {
    float:left;
  width:166.6px;
    height:50px;
    border-left: #005E9C 1px solid;     
}

ul li.menuTopo:last-child { 
  border-right: #005E9C 1px solid;
}

ul li.menuTopo a {
  width:166.6px;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;  
    text-align:center;
    color: #FFF;
  background-color:#3E4095; 
}

ul li.menuTopo a:hover, ul li.menuBase a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color:#CCC;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menuNav">
  <ul class="menuUlTopo">
    <li class="menuTopo"><a href="principal.php" title="Principal">Principal</a></li>
    <li class="menuTopo"><a href="administradoresMenu.php" title="Administradores">Administradores</a></li>
    <li class="menuTopo"><a href="clientesMenu.php" title="Clientes">Clientes</a></li>
    <li class="menuTopo"><a href="imoveisMenu.php" title="Imóveis">Imóveis</a></li>
    <li class="menuTopo"><a href="tiposMenu.php" title="Tipos de Imóveis">Tipos de Imóveis</a></li>
    <li class="menuTopo"><a href="emails.php?acao=listar" title="E-mails">E-mails</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Pro margin 0 auto funcionar tem que definir um width absoluto (não adiante ser percentual)

Comment: .menuNav {
 width:1024px;
 height:50px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color:#3E4095; 
}
Não funcionou

Comment: Se eu tiro o float: left das li's, então o menu se centraliza certinho. E se eu tiro o margin: auto do Reset, também dá certo. Mas nenhum dos 2 posso fazer!

Comment: Então põe float:none no .menuNav

Comment: mesma coisa, Mas .menuNav não esta flutuando. Apenas as li's

Answer (score 0):

Uma possível solução é tirar o `margin: 0 auto;` do elemento `.menuNav` e na sua `ul .menuUlTopo` adicionar `margin: 0 auto;` e `width: 1030px;`

Comment: Não deu certo dessa forma!

Comment: @CarlosRocha Pelo [`código`](https://jsfiddle.net/iigormello/bcjy3y05/) que tenho disponível na pergunta fica centralizado não sei o que tem antes desta `nav`?

Comment: Não tem mais nada. Esse é todo o código.

Comment: Faltou dizer o tamanho da ul dentro do nav. O nav 100%, já a ul 1007px

Comment: Clicou em cima da palavra código no meu comentário para ver como ficou? somente copiei o seu código da pergunta e colei lá e fiz as alterações!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui.

```
.menuNav {
      margin: auto;
      width:1007px;
      background-color:#3E4095; 
}
```